# Resettable Timer object implementation python

Tags: python, timer, reset

I need a timer in Python which i can reset (timer.reset()).
I already have a periodic timer.
Is there a library with such a timer?

```py
class MyTimer(threading.Timer):
    def __init__(self, t):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__event = threading.Event()
        self.__stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.__intervall = t

    def run(self):
        while not self.__stop_event.wait(self.__intervall):
            self.__event.set()

    def clear(self):
        self.__event.clear()

    def is_present(self):
        return self.__event.is_set()

    def cancel(self):
        self.__stop_event.set()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that implements a `reset` method to "extend" the timer by the original interval. It uses an internal `Timer` object rather than subclassing `threading.Timer`.

```
from threading import Timer
import time


class ResettableTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function):
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.timer = Timer(self.interval, self.function)

    def run(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def reset(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = Timer(self.interval, self.function)
        self.timer.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    tim = ResettableTimer(5, lambda: print("Time's Up! Took ", time.time() - t, "seconds"))
    time.sleep(3)
    tim.reset()
```

Output:

`Time's Up! Took  8.011203289031982 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. You should consider adding locks.

```
import threading
import time

def hi( ):
    print('hi')
    mine.start()



class ReusableTime():
    def __init__(self, t, func):
        self._t = t
        self._func = func

    def start(self):
        self._thread = threading.Timer(self._t, self.handler)
        self._thread.start()

    def handler(self):
        self._func()


mine = ReusableTime(2, hi)
mine.start()
time.sleep(100)
```