# counting code giving me 0 instead of a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, arduino-uno

this is my code:

```
from threading import Timer

    timeout = 5
t = Timer(timeout, print, ['Sorry, times up'])
t.start()

count_push1 = + 1
print("Please push the button to count up.You have 5 seconds.")
while True:
   

     if bool(push_button1.read()):
            press_count = + 1
            print(press_count)
            sleep(0.2)
            break
    
        else:
            print('You pressed', press_count, 'times.')
            break
        break
```

I want the user to have 5 seconds.In that 5 seconds, the user will click a button, and timer will reset to 5 seconds.If button is not clicked in 5 seconds,it shows the total number of times user pressed the button.I tried but when I run the code,the code automatically ends.Someone help please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resettable Timer object implementation python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167390/resettable-timer-object-implementation-python)

Comment: not really, i need the timer to reset everytime it detects an output

Comment: Replace your first and last `break` with `timer.reset()` from the given link

Answer (score 0):

You have the order of the operators wrong. In your while loop, you need to change the counter to `count_push1 += 1`

At the top where you define the variable as being 1, I would remove the the `+` for readability.

Edit: `count_push1 += 1` is short for `count_push1 = count_push1 + 1`

Comment: oh ok,but even after than my output is 0

Comment: Your  `break`s are kicking you out of the while loop immediately